Similar pytorch code (involving torch.log) outputs different results at different speeds
I am following Andrej Karpathy's makemore tutorial in which I'm building a character level bigram language model. I first watched the video, and am now working on implementing the solution myself separately. While working on evaluating the model using negative loss likelihood, I noticed that similar code snippets are resulting different outputs.
In the code below, I am evaluating the model P, where P is is a 27x27 tensor where each row is a probability distribution over each bigram.
Here is my code:
# P is a 27x27 tensor where each row is a probability distribution over 27 characters
# SEP = '.'
# names is a list of ~32000 words

def bigram_ll(model, example, verbose=False):
  ll = 0
  for c1, c2 in zip(example, example[1:]):
    i1, i2 = stoi[c1], stoi[c2]
    logprob = torch.log(model[i1, i2])
    ll += logprob
    vprint(verbose, f'{(c1, c2)} {model[i1, i2]:.4f} {logprob:.4f}')
  vprint(verbose, f'{ll=}')

  return ll

def nll(model, words):
  ll = 0.0
  count = 0
  for word in tqdm(words):
    example = [SEP] + list(word) + [SEP]
    ll += bigram_ll(model, example)

    # total samples in example: len(example) - 1 + 2
    count += len(word) + 1
  nll = -ll
  print(f'\nTotal NLL with bigram counting model: {nll}')
  print(f'Average NLL with bigram counting model: {nll / count}')

nll(P, names)

And my output:
100%|██████████| 32033/32033 [00:16<00:00, 1934.57it/s]
Total NLL with bigram counting model: 560002.3125
Average NLL with bigram counting model: 2.4545786380767822

Here is Andrej's code:
log_likelihood = 0.0
n = 0

for w in tqdm(words):
#for w in ["andrejq"]:
  chs = ['.'] + list(w) + ['.']
  for ch1, ch2 in zip(chs, chs[1:]):
    ix1 = stoi[ch1]
    ix2 = stoi[ch2]
    prob = model[ix1, ix2]
    logprob = torch.log(prob)
    log_likelihood += logprob
    n += 1
    #print(f'{ch1}{ch2}: {prob:.4f} {logprob:.4f}')

print(f'{log_likelihood=}')
nll = -log_likelihood
print(f'{nll=}')
print(f'{nll/n}')

And his output:
100%|██████████| 32033/32033 [00:02<00:00, 11498.95it/s]
log_likelihood=tensor(-559951.5625)
nll=tensor(559951.5625)
2.4543561935424805


The second code snippet is much faster than the first, output NLL is different by about 49.5. My first guess is that there are many floating point differences adding up to create a difference of about 50. I also think that maybe pytorch is able to optimize the second snippet because the torch.log is not wrapped in a function. However, this is just speculation.
I don't understand how these 2 snippets of code are doing different things. The first snippet finds the log likelihood of an individual word, then that value is added to the overall counter. The second snippet just has a single counter and continues to add log likelihood of each bigram to it. Why are they outputting different values and why is the second one much faster?
